# What is the proper way of combining time series data with metadata in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-analysis

I have two csv files:

`customer.csv`:

```
id  name     birthday
1   Martin   28.04.1990
2   Twain    30.11.1835
....
```

and `purchases.csv`:

```
purchase_id    customer_id    item                            price
1              1              About the ugly German language  3.14
2              1              Food                            15.92
3              1              Book                            65.35
4              2              Stone                           89.79
```

I can load both dataframes as

```
df_customers = pd.read_csv('customers.csv')
df_purchases = pd.read_csv('purchases.csv')
```

but how can I combine those two, such that I can easily answer the following questions:

- How many items did each customer buy?
- What is the average price of items for each customer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with `right` join:

```
df = pd.merge(df_customers, df_purchases, left_on='id', right_on='customer_id', how='right')
print (df)
   purchase_id  customer_id                            item  price
0            1            1  About the ugly German language   3.14
1            2            1                            Food  15.92
2            3            1                            Book  65.35
3            4            2                           Stone  89.79
   id    name    birthday  purchase_id  customer_id  \
0   1  Martin  28.04.1990            1            1   
1   1  Martin  28.04.1990            2            1   
2   1  Martin  28.04.1990            3            1   
3   2   Twain  30.11.1835            4            2   

                             item  price  
0  About the ugly German language   3.14  
1                            Food  15.92  
2                            Book  65.35  
3                           Stone  89.79
```